# Issue with Javascript date format passed by ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm new to AngularJS, and struggling with a seemingly simple issue. A date value input through ng-model to the ng-controller reads differently (see below) between IE (v8/9/10) and Chrome. This inconsistency makes it difficult to write the code to handle the date on the server end (Python).

How can I make this consistent? (preferably IE format because " GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" is not easy to parse into datetime on the server. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="td_date"  ><datepicker type="text" id="newdate" ng-model="data.date" name="date" bs-datepicker ></div>
Selected date: {{data.date}}  -----> **This prints 2014-09-21T07:10:45.117Z in both browsers**
```

JS:

```
function ($scope, $log, data) {

   $log.info('date ='+ data.date);    ----> **This prints 'Sat Sep 21 00:10:45 PDT 2014' in IE 
                       but 'Sun Sep 21 2014 00:10:45 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)' in Chrome**
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you submitting the form go through the inputs and check for the date objects and format the date to a format u prefer :) so you can get the date in exact format in the backend

```
    if($scope.data.date instanceof Date) {
        $scope.data.date  = $filter('date')($scope.data.date , "yyyy-MM-dd"); // filter to a format u like
    }
```

if your form is in `data` object like `data.date`,'data.userName'...
You can use that as follows When submitting the form,

```
for (key in $scope.data) {
    $scope.data[key] instanceof Date) {
        $scope.data[key] = $filter('date')($scope.data[key], "yyyy-MM-dd"); // filter to a format u like
    }
}
```

here is the api for the date filters in angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

```
function ($scope, $log, data, $filter) {

   $log.info('date ='+ $filter('date')(data.date,'dd-MM-yyyy');   
};
```

Use $filter service of angularjs.
for more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Thank you. This answer solves the problem through @filter just like Kalhano's solution which was provided a bit earlier.